# Using Python 3 matplotlib button - rescale y axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

My spectra data is named "tip16.spe", which has 244 frames. This file is imported as "dset.data[...,0]". I add "matplotlib buttons" function to the Python code. "yset_fun" is a function to call data of the frame number

> `fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>   plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
>   t = xset
>   s = yset_fun(0)
>   l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2.5)`
>
> class Index(object):
>       ind = 0
>       def next(self, event):
>           self.ind += 1
>           i = self.ind % len(dset.data[...,0])
>           ydata = yset_fun(i)
>           l.set_ydata(ydata)
>           plt.draw()
>
> ```
> def prev(self, event):
>     self.ind -= 1
>     i = self.ind % len(dset.data[...,0])
>     ydata = yset_fun(i)
>     l.set_ydata(ydata)
>     plt.draw() 
>
> callback = Index()
> axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
> axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
> bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
> bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
> bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
> bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)
> ```

Then it draws initial data of a fixed y range. But it is bad for data of higher intensity. I want to change it to dynamic range, which means flexible y range can show the whole data.

Could any expert of matplotlib help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You set the y limits via `ax.set_ylim` where `ax` is the axes where you plotted `l` to. You may use the minimum and maximum of the data to determine the limits, `ax.set_ylim(numpy.min(ydata), numpy.max(ydata))`.

Comment: Yes, you got me. Thanks for your help!!